# Sentry intialization crashes with a NoSuchMethodError trying to find jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.registerMethodsToFilter

Tags: java, sentry, jpackage

I'm using `jpackage` (part of jdk14+) to build an MSI for windows installation of my java application. Everything packages and installs fine, but when I go to run the .exe it throws an exception while trying to initialize Sentry.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.registerMethodsToFilter(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String[])'
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.<clinit>(Unsafe.java:59)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.UnsafeReflectionAccessor.getUnsafeInstance(UnsafeReflectionAccessor.java:70)
        at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.UnsafeReflectionAccessor.<init>(UnsafeReflectionAccessor.java:34)
        at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionAccessor.<clinit>(ReflectionAccessor.java:36)
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.<init>(ConstructorConstructor.java:51)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.<init>(Gson.java:206)
        at com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.create(GsonBuilder.java:597)
        at io.sentry.EnvelopeReader.<init>(EnvelopeReader.java:28)
        at io.sentry.SentryOptions.<init>(SentryOptions.java:89)
        at io.sentry.SentryOptions.empty(SentryOptions.java:1559)
        at io.sentry.NoOpHub.<init>(NoOpHub.java:15)
        at io.sentry.NoOpHub.<clinit>(NoOpHub.java:13)
        at io.sentry.Sentry.<clinit>(Sentry.java:24)
```

This is using the latest sentry `5.2.0` library (tested all the way back to `4.2` and it still has the error though), and have tested `JDK` 14 through 17 to see if any of them work, which they don't.

Everything works fine if I'm running the .jar with `java -jar program.jar`, but it seems like `jpackage` creates an executable that doesn't work quite the same as simply running `java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to jpackage needed `--add-modules jdk.internal.vm.compiler` to fix this in JDK14, and by JDK17 it needs to be `--add-modules jdk.unsupported` instead.